# What happens to screen session over ssh when connection is lost?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I ssh to a remote computer, and create a screen session there.  Then I lose the internet connection. When I ssh again to the computer, I want to see if the created screen session is still there, so I run

```
$ screen -l
```

but it seems to me that it doesn't list screen sessions, but create a new session, so I ctrl-d and terminate it.

```
[screen is terminating]
```

Then I run

```
$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-tim
```

Does it mean that losing internet connection will kill any attached screen session?

Note: I tried to reproduce the above scenario except `screen -l`, but surprisingly to me, ssh doesn't lose connection after I deliberately disconnect from the internet, wait for some time and then reconnect again.

Comment: Had you opened the `screen` as a different user than the user you logged in as after reconnecting?

Comment: no. ...........................

Comment: Having the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

`screen` sessions are *not* killed/terminated when the attaching terminal goes away. They are detached just as if you had detached manually (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>, probably). That's part of the point of `screen`.

The disappearance of your `screen` session is due to some other reason. Perhaps the shell running inside the screen exited on its own or the server got rebooted or the contents of `/var/run` were deleted by a "helpful" cleanup cron job.