# What happens to a unix session when the session leader exits?

Tags: posix, process-management

I'm trying to properly emulate POSIX signals handling and job control for [my pet operating system](http://jehanne.io), but it's not clear to me what should happen to a session after the session leader exits.

I cannot find documentation related to what happens to the session and its process if, for example, a child kills the session leader while several background processes and a different foreground process are running.

My tests show that all the process in the session are killed, but how?
Do they receive a specific signal?
Is this case specified in the POSIX standard? And if so, can you provide some references?

Comment: Some related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405755/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84737/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18166/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282973/ .

Comment: @JdeBP interesting links, but it's still hard to say what is expected to happen if the session leader exits. Even considered that the session leader might not be a shell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not the only one puzzled by POSIX sessions; Lennart Poettering (he of `systemd` fame) [is puzzled too](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/pgrp-vs-session.html).

As far as anybody can tell, when a session leader dies, `init` inherits the orphaned session and

- All session member processes in the foreground process group (if any) receive a SIGHUP.
- Session member processes who are not in the foreground group don't receive any signal.

See also:

- [notes.shichao.io/apue/ch9](https://notes.shichao.io/apue/ch9/#sessions)
- Chapter 10 "[Processes](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html)" in  *[The Linux Kernel](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/lk/lk.html)* by Andries Brouwer (2003).

> *If the terminal goes away by modem hangup, and the line was not local, then a SIGHUP is sent to the session leader. [...] When the session leader dies, a SIGHUP is sent to all processes in the foreground process group. [...] Thus, if the terminal goes away and the session leader is a job control shell, then it can handle things for its descendants, e.g. by sending them again a SIGHUP. If on the other hand the session leader is an innocent process that does not catch SIGHUP, it will die, and all foreground processes get a SIGHUP.*
>
> Andries Brower, *The Linux Kernel*, section 10.3 "[Sessions](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html#ss10.3)".

Comment: As for "All session member processes in the foreground process group (if any) receive a SIGHUP.": do you know who send the SIGHUP? In https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84737/in-which-cases-is-sighup-not-sent-to-a-job-when-you-log-out it seems that bash send the signal... and this would invalidate part of your answer.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio: See added quotation from *The Linux Kernel*.